# Removing vertical scrollbar in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How to remove vertical scrollbar in a dropdown?

Comment: If you want jquery solutio then only i can provide you. I am a layman at prototype.

Answer (score 0):

```
.someclass { /* or ID */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: haven't had much luck with any overflow directive on select elements

Comment: @Orbit: hmm .. wasn't mentioned the select element, dropdown could be interpreted as many things actually. In case the OP is looking for that, can't find a reasonable explanation not to allow the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.prismstudio.co.uk/plugins/stylish-select/0.4/#win-xp) under **Windows XP style** menu

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought of a dropdown in the first place :)

Comment: @yoda though i am not so sure if it really does or not

Comment: @Dhines you sure you checked under Windows XP style menu

Comment: @Dhinesh Your link is not working but check out this link http://websmartint.com/demo and look for drop down on right

Comment: @Dhinesh I can provide you jquery solution only

Answer (score 0):

Many web-sites does not actually use the dropdown (select-option) natively in the code since it is very hard to style it.

They usually use a simulation of dropdown using other element and position absolute divs to mock-up the drop down and then they have full control on the styling.

Look at http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html